# What is the name of this component in react?

Tags: reactjs

Could you help me in telling me how to find a component with this structure in react? I will implement something similar in my project.

[image: component]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alberto It is always good to share as many info about your question as possible but not too long stories. In your case, You can tell in words what is required and also if you want to inset some image, insert inline so it is visible to viewers .

However, here is what you want. This is called `Transfer` component from Ant Design.

https://ant.design/components/transfer/

Here is sample code, how api looks like

```
<Transfer
      dataSource={mockData}
      titles={['Source', 'Target']}
      targetKeys={targetKeys}
      selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
      onScroll={this.handleScroll}
      render={item => item.title}
      disabled={disabled}
    />
```